# ¿Como unir una función con dos ID diferentes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy buscando una manera de poder utilizar una función (en este caso `.Datatable()`) en dos `id` diferentes (`$("#ejemplo1")` y `$("#ejemplo2")`) sin tener que repetir el código.

- Ejemplo:

```
$("#ejemplo1").DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "language": idioma
});

$("#ejemplo2").DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "language": idioma
});
```

¿Existe alguna manera posible sin tener que llamar a la función `DataTables()` más de una vez?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si las opciones siempre son las mismas podrías realizar una función a la que le pasaras el id de cada uno de los datatables que quieres rellenar:

```
function rellenarDatatable(ejemplo){
   $(ejemplo).DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "language": idioma
   });
}
```

Después podrías introducir todos los id en un array e ir recorriendolo:

```
var ejemplos = ["#ejemplo1","#ejemplo2","#ejemplo3"...];

ejemplos.forEach(function(ejemplo){
   rellenarDatatable(ejemplo);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

La idea de los id es que sean únicos. Puedes asignarles una clase a todas las tablas que quieras inicializar de la misma manera y luego

```
$("table.ejemplo").DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "language": idioma
});
```

las inicializaría a todas con esa configuración.